# error in mapping statistics multiple groups in grouped violin plots to plot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

Dear all I am trying to plot several genes grouped as control or treated line. Plotting goes fine, but I am having problem when I am trying to add the p.adj value. Can anybody help?

My data frame (df1):

| geneID | gene_name | variable | value | subtype | cell.type | log2value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gene1 | GeneA | ctrl_1 | 2 | controlA | control | 1 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | ctrl_2 | 2.2 | controlA | control | 1.14 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trA_1 | 5 | alpha | treatment | 2.32 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trA_2 | 7 | alpha | treatment | 2.8 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trB_1 | 5 | beta | treatment | 2.32 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trB_2 | 7 | beta | treatment | 2.8 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trC_1 | 5 | delta | treatment | 2.32 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trC_2 | 7 | delta | treatment | 2.8 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trD_1 | 5 | omega | treatment | 2.32 |
| Gene1 | GeneA | trD_2 | 7 | omega | treatment | 2.8 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | ctrl_1 | 10 | controlA | control | 3.3 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | ctrl_2 | 4 | controlA | control | 2 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | trA_1 | 5 | alpha | treatment | 2.32 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | trA_2 | 7 | alpha | treatment | 2.8 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | trB_1 | 2 | beta | treatment | 1 |
| Gene2 | GeneA | trB_2 | 10 | beta | treatment | 3.3 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | trC_1 | 5 | delta | treatment | 2.32 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | trC_2 | 8 | delta | treatment | 3 |
| Gene2 | GeneB | trD_1 | 0 | omega | treatment | -Inf |
| Gene2 | GeneB | trD_2 | 7 | omega | treatment | 2.8 |

Step1:
#This is how I plotted my violin plot-

```
    plt1A <- df1 %>% ggplot(aes(x= Gene_name, y = value,fill = cell.type)) + geom_violin(scale= "width",position = "dodge", adjust=1, width =0.5, trim = FALSE) +` scale_fill_manual(values = c("#E0E0E0", "#A0A0A0")) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_sdl, fun.args = list(mult = 1),geom="pointrange",color="black",shape = 18, size = 0.5,position = position_dodge(width = 0.5))+ theme_bw()+theme(axis.text.x =element_text(size=14, angle = 90)) + theme(panel.grid.major.x =element_blank(),panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

Step2:
#This is where I cehecked for distribution

```
hist1 <- df1 %>% group_by(Gene_name) %>% ggplot(aes(x= value)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5) +facet_wrap(~Gene_name)
hist1
df1$log2rlog <- log2(df1$value)
hist2 <- df1 %>% group_by(Gene_name) %>% ggplot(aes(x= log2rlog)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5) +facet_wrap(~Gene_name)
hist2
```

Since the distribution was not normal for 80% genes I did a Wilcoxin test for testing for significant changes between gene expression between control and treatment cells for each gene.
Step3:
#Testing for significance

```
stat.test <- df1 %>% group_by(Gene_name) %>% wilcox_test(value ~ cell.type,p.adjust.method =  "BH") %>% add_significance()
stat.test
stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "Gene_namee")
```

Step4:
#Adding significance to plot

```
plt1 + + stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "Wilcox-test, p = {p} {p.signif}", y.position = c(11, 14))
```

I get an error for this-

```
Error:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in FUN():
! object 'cell.type' not found
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.

rlang::last_error()

<error/rlang_error>
Error:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'cell.type' not found
---
Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 14. ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
 15. base::lapply(aesthetics, eval_tidy, data = data, env = env)
 16. rlang (local) FUN(X[[i]], ...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

I am not sure what am I doing weird that it is not mapping and plotting my significance values.
Thanks in advance.